# Plugging inequalities into equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have the inequality $3f \leq 2m$. If I wanted to plug this into the equation $n-m+f=2$, how would I do that? Where would I begin?

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the givens:
   $$f=2+m-n$$
   $$f\leq(2/3)m$$

Therefore $$2+m-n\leq (2/3)m$$

Therefore $$2+(1/3)m-n≤0$$ or, if you prefer, $$2+(1/3)m\leq n.$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can replace the $=$ sign with a $≤$ (less than OR equal to) so thus $n-m+f≤2$ adding gets $n-3m+4f≤2$

If your not sure of this use integers to test out this theory!! 
Ex:$3≤3$ and $6≤7$ so $9≤10$

Notice this only works when there is a $≤$ involved